# Reactor mass balance with solid feed and overflow

Tags: applied-chemistry

I am modeling a lime slaker which is basically a stirred tank reactor with two separate feeds:
1. CaO feed screw (powder)
2. H2O binary valve (liquid)

These react according to the reaction:
$\ce{CaO(s) + H2O(l) -> Ca(OH)2(s)}$

The slaker is operated on a semibatch fashion where water and lime are fed until the desired amounts have been added and when the reaction has finished a new batch can be started. Water is added in excess with a mass ratio of approximately 1:4. The addition of the reactants takes about six minutes and after that some minutes are required for the temperature to rise due to the reaction. The reactor is **not** emptied between the batches but the contents exit to a secondary tank through internal piping on an overflow basis. An example of the development of the reactor temperature is given below.
[image: Temperature]

Because of the overflow the volume of the reactor (and the contents) stays constant. The output feed is not measured. In general, the material balance of a model is:

the rate of accumulation of mass in the system = rate of mass entering the system - rate of mass leaving the system

or

$\frac{dM}{dt}=\dot{m}_{in}-\dot{m}_{out}$

or

$\frac{dV\rho}{dt}=\dot{F}_{in}\rho_{in}-\dot{F}_{out}\rho$.

For the lime addition weighing data is available to determine the mass of the added quicklime. The lime feed screw is operated at a constant speed so the feed rate can be determined. The water feed has a flow measurement.

What would be the best way to form the material balances as the reaction happens between a liquid and a solid? How to determine how much material is displaced by the addition of lime? How does the formation of calcium hydroxide affect the balance?